# How to override SOQL queries for testing

Tags: soql, unit-test

I understand that test methods should create all data needed for the method and not rely on data currently in the org. However, how can I mock out SOQL queries which generate data for use within other methods?

Here's a simplified version of what I mean:

```
public List<User> getUserEmailList {
  return [SELECT Email FROM User];
}

public List<User> getUsernameList {
  return [SELECT Username FROM User];
}

public String processUsers(List<User> userList) {
  String myResult;
  for (user :userList) {
    //do something;
  } 

  return myResult;
}

public String getSomeData(String type) {
  String userList;
  if (type == 'email') {userList = getUserEmailList();}
  else if (type == 'username') {userList = getUsernameList();}

  return processUsers(userList);
}
```

So I can effectively test the processUsers method because I can feed it a list of mock user objects, but am unable to test the getSomeData method. If I try and test the getSomeData method then one of the SOQL queries will be fired and I am no longer in control of my test data.

Comment: in short: you can compose data and insert it with DML. This will only be inserted into a memory database state for the duration of the test method.

Comment: Like you said in the beginning of the question, you create your own test data to feed the queries.

Answer (score 7):

When you execute your Apex test method, the test context creates a special set of circumstances that allow this to work. In this instance, you can insert, update, delete, undelete data, it will be saved to the db, but not committed.

So if you were to do this test (assuming your class is called TheClass):

```
@isTest
public class TestClass {
  public static testMethod test1(){
    TheClass tc = new TheClass();
    User u = new User(username='a@b.c',email='a@b.c', ...put more field values here...);
    insert u; 

    Test.startTest();
    List<User> testUsers = tc.getSomeData('email');
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals('a@b.c',testUsers.get(0).email);
  }//end of scope of test so test data goes away
}
```

Provided my freehand code is correct (which it probably isnt'), I would expect the assert here to be true. The scope of the test data  is the from the point it is created in your test method, until your test method ends.

So you create data that should give you the desired result, run it through your method, then check to make sure that you got the desired result.

Comment: This seems like a great solution for most cases. I was unaware that once the test starts the data scope starts from test creation time. The problem for me is that I need to calculate Case age specifically. So I need control over the Case.CreatedDate. I created my own ApexMox class which serializes a Map of Case fields into a Case object which lets me override this readonly field. You can even insert the object. However, after messing with this I found that if you query for what was inserted then Salesforce will simply override this field and put in the correct CreatedDate.

Answer (score 0):

Since I need control over a read only field such as CreatedDate. I was able to solve this problem like this:

```
public MyClass() {
  this.userList = null;
}

public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
  this.userList = userList    
}

public List<User> getUserEmailList {
  if (Test.isRunningTest()) {return this.userList;}
  return [SELECT Email FROM User];
}

public List<User> getUsernameList {
  if (Test.isRunningTest()) {return this.userList;}
  return [SELECT Username FROM User];
}

public String processUsers(List<User> userList) {
  String myResult;
  for (user :userList) {
    //do something;
  } 

  return myResult;
}

public String getSomeData(String type) {
  String userList;
  if (type == 'email') {userList = getUserEmailList();}
  else if (type == 'username') {userList = getUsernameList();}

  return processUsers(userList);
}
```

This way, from my test class I can simply override SOQL query execution altogether and provide my own list of objects. What I ended up doing in the unit tests looks something like:

```
@isTest
  public static testThings() {
    MyClass t = new MyClass();
    User testUser = new User();
    t.setUserList(new List<User> {testUser});

    // do some testing
  }
```

Works for me, although it seems to be slightly hacky. Anyone have any thoughts on this solution?

Comment: A common scenario is to do this with a constructor parameter, such as the example code for batch apex code.